# Grafico correlações (round)

Tags: r

Como criar um gráfico (round graph no ellipse) de correlações entre 20 caracteres quando eu já tenho a tabela de correlações pronta e não preciso calcular a correlação no R?

Comment: Tem como nos mostrar um exemplo deste gráfico? [Imagino que seja algo como este gráfico](http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/figure/statistics/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram-correlogram-methods1.png), mas gostaria de ter certeza disso.